# Stop VMPlayer from shutdown script got force close screen

Tags: vmware, batch-processing, vmware-player

i'm using windows7 and VMPlayer for Virtual Machines, at the moment i already create a batch script to shut it down (using vmrun) and already register it on Shutdown Script on local group policy (Configuration/Windows Settings/Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)).

My problem is, everytime i start a shutdown, my windows pop-up a force close screen before the script executed which my the shutdown script worthless.

Is there any solution on this ?

i already read a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782944/run-a-batch-file-on-windows-7-shutdown-before-closing-programs-preferrably-on-p) but i think the solution is on hibernate not a complete shutdown